Can't get the panel of my plugin into the 3D view & Different problems depending on panel locations
I have written a plugin with two simple options. Option 1 reads transformation values from selected objects and their child objects while option 2 makes simple operations in 3D space like add and parent objects. These work fine if you run them individually in the scripting tab.
However, when I run them from the panel of my plugin, only one of them works, depending on which tab of the properties the panel is in. If it is in the Collection tab, option 1 does not work, if it is in the Object Properties tab, option 2 does not work.
So I assume that these tab locations cause certain information in the 3D space to be ignored and it is probably a better idea to place the panel in the 3D viewport, so I followed this step, but to no avail:
How to add panel into 3D view port (beside object 3D)
I get this error when starting the plugin. If I leave the panel in the Properites tab I don't get it:

I can't find the error. Is there a way to set it so that no matter where the panel is, it only accesses the 3D View objects, or is the panel error fixable after all?
Here is my code:
import bpy
import math
import os

def CamXYexport(context):
    option1 code here


def CamCreate(context):
    option2 code here

class GalaxycamOperator1(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Copy camera code for XY Camera"""
    bl_idname = "object.galaxycam_operator1"
    bl_label = "XY PARA"
    def execute(self, context):
        CamXYexport(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    
class GalaxycamOperator2(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add camera with reference objects"""
    bl_idname = "objecto.galaxycam_operator2"
    bl_label = "Add Camera"
    def execute(self, context):
        CamCreate(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    

#LAYOUT -----------------------------------------------------

class LayoutSMGCameraPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Camera Addon"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_GalaxyCameraGenerator_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_context = "Item"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        
        # Big render button
        layout.label(text="Copy Camera Code")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.2
        row.operator("object.galaxycam_operator1", icon='MESH_CUBE')

        layout.label(text="Camera Actions")
        row = layout.row()
        row.scale_y = 1.2
        row.operator("objecto.galaxycam_operator2", icon='MESH_CUBE')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(GalaxycamOperator1)
    bpy.utils.register_class(GalaxycamOperator2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutSMGCameraPanel)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GalaxycamOperator1)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(GalaxycamOperator2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutSMGCameraPanel)
    
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


It is recommended to post runnable code, To debug, delete the code in the CamXYexport function one by one until you no longer see the error message. Then tell us which line is causing the problem.

This error seems to show the panel is already registered somewhere else.

Thank you! I just found out, it didn't worked because an earlier version of the script with the layout in the properties panel was already running. Restarting Blender and running the newer script makes the plugin show up in the 3D View as it should.
